# How did R-square get its name?

Tags: r-squared, history

How did `R-square` get its name? I understand how its calculated and interpreted, but I do not understand the **r** and **square** part of it.

Comment: There is also a complementary question ["Why is $r$ used to denote correlation?"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/368224/why-is-r-used-to-denote-correlation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$R$, $r$, or Pearson's $r$ is the Pearson product-moment correlation coefficient, or simply correlation. In a linear regression with an intercept, $R^2$ is the squared correlation between the dependent variable and the fitted values; hence the R-squared. This is also supported by [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination#As_squared_correlation_coefficient), with some additional information:

> In linear least squares multiple regression with an estimated intercept term, $R^2$ equals the square of the Pearson correlation coefficient between the observed $y$ and modeled (predicted) $f$ data values of the dependent variable.
>
> In a linear least squares regression with an intercept term and a single explanator, this is also equal to the squared Pearson correlation coefficient of the dependent variable $y$ and explanatory variable $x$.

Comment: The more interesting question is where did R itself get its name from? 

Comment: @IsabellaGhement, why wouldn't you post this question (unless it has been asked before)? I would upvote it. By the way, the OP seems fine with **R** itself, and the question is specifically about the **square** part (not that you would have claimed otherwise, of course).

Comment: It's funny, but I feel more comfortable answering questions that asking them on this forum, Richard. Please go ahead and ask it for me - it would be nice to get an answer to it!

Comment: @IsabellaGhement, it is your choice. Thank you for giving me the opportunity. [Here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/368224/why-is-r-used-to-denote-correlation) is the question.